# Why shouldn't Java enum literals be able to have generic type parameters?

Tags: java, generics, enums

Java enums are great. So are generics. Of course we all know the limitations of the latter because of type erasure. But there is one thing I don't understand, Why can't I create an enum like this:

```
public enum MyEnum<T> {
    LITERAL1<String>,
    LITERAL2<Integer>,
    LITERAL3<Object>;
}
```

This generic type parameter `<T>` in turn could then be useful in various places. Imagine a generic type parameter to a method:

```
public <T> T getValue(MyEnum<T> param);
```

Or even in the enum class itself:

```
public T convert(Object o);
```

#### More concrete example #1

Since the above example might seem too abstract for some, here's a more real-life example of why I want to do this. In this example I want to use

- Enums, because then I can enumerate a finite set of property keys
- Generics, because then I can have method-level type-safety for storing properties

```
public interface MyProperties {
     public <T> void put(MyEnum<T> key, T value);
     public <T> T get(MyEnum<T> key);
}
```

#### More concrete example #2

I have an enumeration of data types:

```
public interface DataType<T> {}

public enum SQLDataType<T> implements DataType<T> {
    TINYINT<Byte>,
    SMALLINT<Short>,
    INT<Integer>,
    BIGINT<Long>,
    CLOB<String>,
    VARCHAR<String>,
    ...
}
```

Each enum literal would obviously have additional properties based on the generic type `<T>`, while at the same time, being an enum (immutable, singleton, enumerable, etc. etc.)

#### Question:

Did no one think of this? Is this a compiler-related limitation? Considering the fact, that the keyword "**enum**" is implemented as syntactic sugar, representing generated code to the JVM, I don't understand this limitation.

Who can explain this to me? Before you answer, consider this:

- I know generic types are erased :-)
- I know there are workarounds using Class objects. They're workarounds.
- Generic types result in compiler-generated type casts wherever applicable (e.g. when calling the convert() method
- The generic type <T> would be on the enum. Hence it is bound by each of the enum's literals. Hence the compiler would know, which type to apply when writing something like `String string = LITERAL1.convert(myObject); Integer integer = LITERAL2.convert(myObject);`
- The same applies to the generic type parameter in the `T getvalue()` method. The compiler can apply type casting when calling `String string = someClass.getValue(LITERAL1)`

Comment: I don't understand this limitation either.  I came across this recently where my enum contained different "Comparable" types, and with generics, only Comparable types of the same types can be compared without warnings that need to be suppressed (even though at runtime the proper ones would be compared).  I could have gotten rid of these warnings by using a type bound in the enum to specify which comparable type was supported, but instead I had to add the SuppressWarnings annotation - no way around it!  Since compareTo does throw a class cast exception anyways, it's ok I guess, but still...

Comment: I voted to close my own question as being "not constructive". This question probably cannot be answered without starting to rant either about the JCP's decisions about language design or about my own intent (e.g. [the originally accepted, but deleted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters#7231291), for those who can see deleted answers)...

Comment: (+1) I'm just in the middle of trying to close a type safety gap in my project, stopped dead by this arbitrary limitation. Just consider this: turn the `enum` into a "typesafe enum" idiom we used before Java 1.5. Suddenly, you can have your enum members parameterized. That's probably what I'm going to do now.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: That's one thing you can do, but you'll lose all the awesome enum features that are baked into the language and JDK. For instance `switch` support, or `EnumSet` and `EnumMap`

Comment: I know, it's bad :) In fact, I had to drop it for one of the two enums where I wanted to apply it.

Comment: I have a hard thinking of a scenario where that could be useful. Do you have a more concrete scenario?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: Updated the question with a concrete example from [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), where this would have been immensely useful in the past.

Comment: @LukasEder I see your point now. Looks like a cool a new feature. Maybe you should suggest it in [project coin mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/coin-dev) I see other interesting proposals there on enums, but not one like yours.

Comment: Totally agree. Enum without generics are crippled. Your case #1 is also mine. If I need generic enum I give up JDK5 and implement it in plain old Java 1.4 style. This approach has also *additional benefit*: I'm not forced to have all constants in one class or even package. Thus, package-by-feature style is accomplished a lot better. This is perfect just for configuration-like "enums" - constants are spread in packages according to their logical meaning (and if I wish to see them all, I have type hieararchy shown).

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: Is that list still active? Anyway, I didn't make any awesome experience on those lists in the past...

Comment: Actually, this is a really good question. It's a shame to see that pretty much all the answers are either missing the point or disregarding the problem entirely. In a way I suppose that's to be expected, though, seeing as there seems to be no obvious answer.

Comment: A good idea, but it does add extra to the JLS, making maintenance and new features so much harder, hence all the resistance. Java is already hacked back and forth for backwards compatibility reasons, keeping it pure is I think a #1 prio by now. So it's a fair argument that if you need this level of complexity in your enums, maybe you should model this with OO instead.

Comment: What do you mean by *"keeping it pure"*. Also, how are generic enums a) complex and b) not OO? Besides, did you check http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301?

Comment: Another example why this is a must have, I had a game where I had lots of assets, images, videos, sounds, 3d models. I had to load all these things and turn them into an object. Now I needed to have an enum per asset type to define all of these. With generic enums like this: https://github.com/Leejjon/BluffPoker/blob/master/core/src/main/java/net/leejjon/bluffpoker/enums/TextureKey.java With generic enums I could have one big enum with multiple asset types, and still loop over then to create all these objects and get back the correct types.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This has been discussed as of [JEP-301 Enhanced Enums](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301), which was withdrawn, regrettably. The example given in the JEP is, which is precisely what I was looking for:

```
enum Argument<X> { // declares generic enum
   STRING<String>(String.class), 
   INTEGER<Integer>(Integer.class), ... ;

   Class<X> clazz;

   Argument(Class<X> clazz) { this.clazz = clazz; }

   Class<X> getClazz() { return clazz; }
}

Class<String> cs = Argument.STRING.getClazz(); //uses sharper typing of enum constant
```

Unfortunately, the JEP was struggling with significant issues, which couldn't be resolved: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2017-May/000041.html

Comment: As of December 2018, there were some [signs of life around JEP 301 again](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2018-December/000876.html), but skimming that discussion makes it clear that the problems are still far from solved.

Comment: This JEP was withdrawn in September 2020: [withdrawing comment](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170351?focusedCommentId=14371268&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14371268)

Answer (score 17):

The answer is in the question:

> because of type erasure

None of these two methods are possible, since the argument type is erased.

```
public <T> T getValue(MyEnum<T> param);
public T convert(Object);
```

To realise those methods you could however construct your enum as:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    LITERAL1(String.class),
    LITERAL2(Integer.class),
    LITERAL3(Object.class);

    private Class<?> clazz;

    private MyEnum(Class<?> clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: Well, erasure takes place at compile-time. But the compiler can use generic type information for type-checks. And then "converts" the generic type to type casts. I'll rephrase the question

Comment: Not sure I entirely follow. Take `public T convert(Object);`. I'm guessing this method could for instance narrow a bunch of different types to <T>, which for instance is a String. The construction of the String object is runtime - nothing the compiler does. Hence you need to know the runtime type, such as String.class. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that the generic type <T> is on the enum (or its generated class). The only instances of the enum are its literals, which all provide a constant generic type binding. Hence there is no ambiguity about T in public T convert(Object);

Comment: Aha! Got it. You're cleverer than me :)

Comment: I guess it comes down to the class for a enum being evaluated in a similar way to everything else. In java, although things *seem* constant, they aren't. Consider `public final static String FOO;` with a static block `static { FOO = "bar"; }` - also constants are evaluated even when known at compile time.

Comment: "None of these two methods are possible" --> so are they or not ?

Answer (score 5):

There are other methods in ENUM that wouldn't work. What would `MyEnum.values()` return?

What about `MyEnum.valueOf(String name)`?

For the valueOf if you think that compiler could make generic method like

> public static  MyEnum valueOf(String name);

in order to call it like `MyEnum<String> myStringEnum = MyEnum.value("some string property")`, that wouldn't work either.
For example what if you call `MyEnum<Int> myIntEnum = MyEnum.<Int>value("some string property")` ?
It is not possible to implement that method to work correctly, for example to throw exception or return null when you call it like `MyEnum.<Int>value("some double property")` because of type erasure.

Comment: Why wouldn't they work? They'd simply use wildcards...: `MyEnum<?>[] values()` and `MyEnum<?> valueOf(...)`

Comment: But then you could not do assignment like this `MyEnum<Int> blabla = valueOf("some double property");` because the types are not compatible.
Also you want in that case to get null because you want to return MyEnum<Int> which does not exists for double property name and you cannot make that method work properly because of erasure.

Comment: Also if you loop through values() you would need to use MyEnum<?> which is not what you want usually because for example you cannot loop through only your Int properties. Also you would need to do a lot of casting which you want to avoid, I would suggest to create different enums for every type or make your own class with instances...

Comment: Well, I guess you cannot have both. Usually, I resort to my own "enum" implementations. It's just that `Enum` has a lot of other useful features, and this one would be optional and very useful as well...

Answer (score 4):

Because you can't. Seriously. That could be added to the language spec. It hasn't been. It would add some complexity. That benefit to cost means it isn't a high priority.

Update: Currently being added to the language under [JEP 301: Enhanced Enums](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the complications ?

Comment: I have been thinking about this for a couple of days now, and I still see no complications.

Answer (score 1):

By using this Java annotation processor https://github.com/cmoine/generic-enums, you can write something like (the convert method were implemented as an example):

```java
import org.cmoine.genericEnums.GenericEnum;
import org.cmoine.genericEnums.GenericEnumParam;

@GenericEnum
public enum MyEnum {
    LITERAL1(String.class) {
        @Override
        @GenericEnumParam
        public Object convert(Object o) {
            return o.toString(); // example
        }
    },
    LITERAL2(Integer.class) {
        @Override
        @GenericEnumParam
        public Object convert(Object o) {
            return o.hashCode(); // example
        }
    },
    LITERAL3(Object.class) {
        @Override
        @GenericEnumParam
        public Object convert(Object o) {
            return o; // example
        }
    };

    MyEnum(Class<?> clazz) {
    }

    @GenericEnumParam
    public abstract Object convert(Object o);
}
```

The annotation processor will generate an enum `MyEnumExt` (customizable) which overcomes the limitation of java enums. Instead, it generates a Java class usable exactly as an enum (in the end, an enum is compiled into a Java class implementing `Enum` !).

Answer (score -2):

Frankly this seems like more of a solution in search of a problem than anything.

The entire purpose of the java enum is to model a enumeration of type instances that share similiar properties in a way that provides consistency and richness beyond that of comparable String or Integer representations.

Take an example of a text book enum. This is not very useful or consistent:

```
public enum Planet<T>{
    Earth<Planet>,
    Venus<String>,
    Mars<Long>
    ...etc.
}
```

Why would I want my different planets to have different generic type conversions? What problem does it solve? Does it justify complicating the language semantics? If I do need this behavior is an enum the best tool to achieve it?

Additionally how would you manage complex conversions?

for Instance

```
public enum BadIdea<T>{
   INSTANCE1<Long>,
   INSTANCE2<MyComplexClass>;
}
```

Its easy enough with `String` `Integer` to supply the name or ordinal. But generics would allow you to supply any type. How would you manage the conversion to `MyComplexClass`? Now your mucking up two constructs by forcing the compiler to know that there are a limited subset of types that can be supplied to generic enums and introducing additional confusion to concept(Generics) that already seems elude a lot of programmers.

Comment: Its philosophical more than anything. enum instances are not intended to representative of "properties" of various generic types. The instances are instances of the enum's type. Your suggested "feature" violates the intent of the construct to solve a problem related to a specific somewhat questionable application.

Comment: Thinking of a couple of examples where it would not be useful is a terrible argument that it would never be useful.

Comment: The examples support the point. The enum instances are subclasses of the type(nice and simple) and that including generics is a can of worms it terms of complexity for a very obscure benefit. If you are going to downvote me then you should also downvote Tom Hawtin below who said the same thing in not so many words

Comment: Keep in mind that enums are also a way to create singleton (or N-ton) instances. Say you have a list of convertable types... `StringifierEnum`. And you want to generify it `NUMBER.convert(Number)`, `CURRENCY.convert(Double)`, `TO_STRING.convert(Object)`, `LYRICS.convert(String[])`... Why should they all be forced to take `Object` as an argument type? Why not generify it with `StringifierEnum<T>` and `public abstract String convert ( T object )`? Inability to use generics here keeps easily detectable errors from being detected at compile time and moves them to run time.

Comment: I think my feeling on this is as follows. Yes, creating singleton's is a common application of an `enum`, but what you are describing is not an `enum`. You are describing something different. Adding generics to the enumeration just muddies the concept of an `enum` to satisfy the practical considerations of what you want to use the `enum` for. I think if you want this capability it should be delivered through some other construct.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't the severity is at question here. Language design decisions were made and I just haven't heard a compelling reason to change them. Cursory glance implies that yes in this particular instance it would allow OP to implement their solution using an `enum`, but does it solve a fundamental language limitation? My intuition tells me no. Enums are simple and solve a simple problem. They are fine as they are and should be left alone.

Comment: @nsfyn55 Enums are one of the most complex, most magical language features of Java. There isn't a single other language feature which auto-generates static methods, for example. Plus, each enum type already *is* an instance of a generic type.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Complex, magical? They are called `enum` for a reason. Their job is to enumerate a finite list of instances belonging to a class. People have repurposed them in clever ways, but this doesn't imply that the feature's design impetus has changed.

Comment: @nsfyn55 The design goal was to make enum members powerful and flexible, which is why they support such advanced features as custom instance methods and even mutable instance variables. They are designed to have *behavior* specialized for each member individually so they can participate as active collaborators in complex usage scenarios. Most of all, the Java enum was designed to make the general enumeration idiom *type safe*, but the lack of type parameters unfortunately makes it fall short of that most cherished goal. I am quite convinced that there was a *very specific* reason for that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik There is a specific reason and its already been mentioned a bazillion times. Type Erasure. The instances of your generisized `Option` or `Property` classes lose their type identity at run time.

Comment: @nsfyn55 All the responses mentioning type erasure are missing the point: this is about *compile-time* type safety. I have already posted a specific example, so let me repost it here for your convenience: `class Emun<E extends Emun<E>> { } abstract class Xenu<T> extends Emun<Xenu<T>> { abstract T convert(Object o); static Xenu<String> STRING = new Xenu<String>() { String convert(Object o) { return o.toString(); } }; String s = STRING.convert(3); }` BTW did you know that all languages with a truly competent type system, such as Haskell, also have type erasure?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik no offense but for someone hung up on the beauty of type safety thats a rather hamfisted approach. Accept something of type `Object` and apply a blind conversion? It works ok with a `String` but what about a less contrived example. `class MyComplexClassConverter { MyComplexClass convert(Object o) { // lets hope I don't explode in your face }}` to do this properly java would have to support contravariance.

Comment: @nsfyn55 You are now descending into the level of detail which an example inlined into a comment (a) cannot possibly cover and (b) has no need to because its purpose is proving one and only one assertion. And if you are referring to OP's ideas, he is the author of the jOOQ library which often needs to work with a well-defined, closed set of types. My use case is quite different, but again I work with a closed and well-defined set of types.

Comment: I didn't notice your mention of contravariance... Java *does* support it, only it's use-site, which makes it a bit unwieldy. `interface Converter<IN, OUT> { OUT convert(IN in); } 
  
  <E> Set<E> convertListToSet(List<E> in, Converter<? super List<E>, ? extends Set<E>> converter) { 
    return converter.convert(in); 
  }` We have to manually work out each time which type is consumed and which produced, and specify the bounds accordingly.

Comment: Of course it's useful. The OP gave a perfect example - and there are many more. Every case where each enum value requires one or more particular types as parameters/specializations of their behaviour, e.g. `EARTH<EarthProperties>, MARS<MarsProperties>`

Comment: @Navigateur No language will ever be complete. In my mind "Useful" is not the correct discriminator. I am looking for is "Necessary" You have to draw a line in the sand somewhere. This line is the decision that the language reasonably supports its intended use cases. There is nothing wrong with what you and OP are proposing. It just sits on the wrong side of my line.

Comment: @nsyfn55 I was expecting the feature to already exist, to the extent that I even typed it out in my IDE to use in my app. The enum contructor is the only constructor that doesn't accept type params, and allowing it would simply bring enums in line with the rest of the language, as well as reducing code complexity for achieving the same task. So this is well, well on the right side of the line for me. In fact my standard for language features is minimization of code complexity. In very complex apps that makes a big difference

Answer (score -4):

I think because basically Enums can't be instanced

Where would you set the T class, if JVM allowed you to do so?

Enumeration is data that is supposed to be always the same, or at least, that it won't change dinamically.

new MyEnum<>()?

Still the following approach may be useful

```
public enum MyEnum{

    LITERAL1("s"),
    LITERAL2("a"),
    LITERAL3(2);

    private Object o;

    private MyEnum(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    public Object getO() {
        return o;
    }

    public void setO(Object o) {
        this.o = o;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Not sure I like the `setO()` method on an `enum`. I consider enums constants and to me that implies **immutable**. So even if it's possible, I wouldn't do it.

Comment: Enums are instanciated in the code generated by the compiler. Each literal is actually created by calling the private constructors. Hence, there would be a chance to pass the generic type to the constructor at compile-time.

Comment: Setters on enums are completely normal. Especially if you're using the enum to create a singleton (Item 3 Effective Java by Joshua Bloch)

Answer (score -4):

Becasue "enum" is the abbreviation for enumeration.
It's just a set of named constants that stand in place of ordinal numbers to make the code better readable.

I don't see what the intended meaning of a type-parameterized constant could be.

Comment: In `java.lang.String`: `public static final Comparator<String> CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`. You see now? :-)

Comment: You said you don't see what the meaning of a type-parameterised constant could be. So I showed you a type-parameterised constant (not a function pointer).

Comment: Of course not, as the java language does not know such a thing as a function pointer. Still, not the constant is type parameterized, but it's type. And the type parameter itself is constant, not a type variable.

Comment: But the enum syntax is just syntactic sugar. Underneath, they're exactly like `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`... If `Comparator<T>` were an enum, why not have literals with any associated bound for `<T>`?

Comment: If Comparator<T> were an enum, then indeed we could have all sorts of weird things. Perhaps something like Integer<T>. But it isn't.

Comment: Check out the updated question. I added a more real-life example to illustrate my use case