# Java enums and generics

Tags: java, generics, enums

This thing is troubling me for a while now. I have asked [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters) before, but probably with a bad phrasing and an example that was too abstract. So it wasn't clear what I was actually asking. I'll try again. And please don't jump to conclusions. I expect that the question is not easy at all to answer!

**why can't I have an enum with generic type parameters in Java?**

The question is not about why it's not possible, syntactically. I know it's just not supported. The question is: why did the JSR people "forget" or "omit" this very useful feature? I can't imagine a compiler-related reason, why it wouldn't be feasible.

Here's what I would love to do. This is possible in Java. It's the Java 1.4 way to create typesafe enums:

```
// A model class for SQL data types and their mapping to Java types
public class DataType<T> implements Serializable, Comparable<DataType<T>> {
    private final String name;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public static final DataType<Integer> INT      = new DataType<Integer>("int", Integer.class);
    public static final DataType<Integer> INT4     = new DataType<Integer>("int4", Integer.class);
    public static final DataType<Integer> INTEGER  = new DataType<Integer>("integer", Integer.class);
    public static final DataType<Long>    BIGINT   = new DataType<Long>   ("bigint", Long.class);    

    private DataType(String name, Class<T> type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Returns T. I find this often very useful!
    public T parse(String string) throws Exception {
        // [...]
    }

    // Check this out. Advanced generics:
    public T[] parseArray(String string) throws Exception {
        // [...]
    }

    // Even more advanced:
    public DataType<T[]> getArrayType() {
        // [...]
    }

    // [ ... more methods ... ]
}
```

And then, you could use `<T>` in many other places

```
public class Utility {

    // Generic methods...
    public static <T> T doStuff(DataType<T> type) {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

But these things are not possible with an enum:

```
// This can't be done
public enum DataType<T> {

    // Neither can this...
    INT<Integer>("int", Integer.class), 
    INT4<Integer>("int4", Integer.class), 

    // [...]
}
```

Now, as I said. I know these things have been designed exactly that way. `enum` is syntactic sugar. So are generics. Actually, the compiler does all the work and transforms `enums` into subclasses of `java.lang.Enum` and generics into casts and synthetic methods.

**but why can't the compiler go further and allow for generic enums??**

**EDIT**:
This is what I would expect as compiler-generated Java code:

```
public class DataType<T> extends Enum<DataType<?>> {
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why shouldn't Java enum literals be able to have generic type parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters)

Comment: Well, I said I asked the question again but in a clearer phrasing because the other question just gave me rubbish answers (in my opinion). I'd prefer closing the other one...

Comment: @Lukas Eder So improve the original question. Doesn't look like re-asking the question has helped.

Comment: It is not a matter of feasibility its a matter of what will this actually break in deployments?  Also, why do you need this functionality?

Comment: I have done that before on stackoverflow and then I was criticised and told to ask a new question... could you guys make up your mind? :)

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Why? I think the example shows a very good use case...? And I'm sure in C# this is possible

Comment: @Lukas because Oracle doesn't feel like irritating a bunch of customers?  C# != JAVA

Comment: @Woot4Moo. It's not just the work of Oracle. Ture, they irritate me every day with PL/SQL. So maybe they start doing it with Java as well :). And C# != JAVA... Oh well...

Comment: @Lukas Eder Your example doesn't make sense and I showed you why.

Comment: @biziclop. Why doesn't it make sense? I think you don't understand how generics work in Java...

Comment: @Lukas Eder I showed you exactly why. If you don't understand my answer, you can always ask for more clarification. Although if you prefer insulting others to undestanding, that's fine too.

Comment: @biziclop, I'm sorry, there's a misunderstanding. I didn't mean to insult. Please clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to guess a bit and say that it is because of covariance issues on the type parameter of the Enum class itself, which is defined as `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`, although it is a bit much to investigate all the corner cases of that.

Besides that, a primary use case of enums is with things like EnumSet and valueOf where you have a collection of things with different generic parameters and get the value from a string, all of which would not support or worse the generic parameter on the enum itself.

I know I'm always in a world of pain when I try to get that fancy with Generics, and I imagine the language designers peeked at that abyss and decided to not go there, especially since the features were developed concurrently, which would mean even more uncertainty for the Enum side of things.

Or put another way, it would have all the problems of `Class<T>` in dealing with classes which themselves have generic parameters, and you would have to do a lot of casting and dealing with raw types. Not truly something that the language designers felt was worth it for the type of use case you are looking at.

<strike>EDIT: In response to the comments (and Tom - a downvote?), nested generic parameter makes all kinds of bad things happen. Enum implements Comparable. That simply would not work to compare two arbitrary elements of the enum in client code if generics were in play. Once you deal with a Generic parameter of a Generic parameter, you end up with all kinds of bounds problems and headaches. It is hard to design a class that handles it well. In the case of comparable, I could not figure out a way to make it work to compare two arbitrary members of an enum without reverting to raw types and getting a compiler warning. Could you?</strike>

Actually the above is embarrassingly wrong, as I was using the DataType in the question as my template for thinking about this, but in fact an Enum would have a subclass, so that isn't quite right.

However, I stand by the gist of my answer. Tom brought up `EnumSet.complementOf` and of course we still have `valueOf` that produces problems, and to the degree that the design of Enum could have worked, we have to realize that that is a 20/20 hindsight thing. Enum was being designed concurrently with generics and didn't have the benefit of validating all such corner cases. Especially considering that the use case for an Enum with a generic parameter is rather limited. (But then again, so is the use case for EnumSet).

Comment: +1 Very nice answer. I hardly use `EnumSet`. I can see that they would get in the way with my `<T>` generic type

Comment: One example (that involves Class being generic) that would be strange is the Enum.valueOf method. Its first argument should be the enum class. But now you have a problem: if you pass it Class<DataType>, you get a raw type warning, and you can't pass it Class<DataType<Integer>> (what would that even mean, if you could get a hold of it in a type-safe way?).

Comment: I can't see anything that makes sense in there.

Comment: I thought about this again. `public enum DataType<T>` being generated to `public class DataType<T> extends Enum<DataType<T>>` is wrong, because `<T>` can be bound for every instance, which is not supported by `Enum<E>`. This might work though: `public class DataType<T> extends Enum<DataType<?>>`. And I don't see a problem for `EnumSet` when `E` is bound to `DataType<?>`...

Comment: `class En<T extends En<T>> { } class DateType<T> extends En<DateType<T>> { } class IntegerDateType extends DateType<Integer> { }` Works out fine for me. At least that far. We will have `EnumSet<DataType<?>>` semi-usefully, although we also have  `EnumSet<DataType<Integer>>`. And unfortunately the last becomes a little problematic when we use `EnumSet.complementOf` or `EnumSet.range`.

Comment: @Tom and @Lukas, I think you guys are way overthinking this. Just try to make the Comparator work. I'll update my answer to expand on some further thoughts.

Comment: @Yishai `Comparable` just works. There need be no changes to the `Enum` class which implements `Comparable` (with a `final` `compareTo` method).

Comment: @Tom, It took me a bit to figure out how you could say that, then I got it. You are talking about the implementation itself. I'm not, I'm talking about calling it as a client. I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: @Yishai You mean if you were using `Collections.max`, say, you'd need, say, a `Collection<DataType<Integer>>` instead of `Collection<DataType<?>>`. Yup. Does that matter? (You can, of course, write your own `Comparator<DataType<?>>`, if you **really** wanted for some reason.)

Comment: I was missing on some things here... I guess you guys didn't get much farther, other than just not being sure *why* Enums weren't designed that way... Maybe we'll never know :-) Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is impossible to have generified enum. If you could hack into compiler, you can have a subclass of Enum that is generic, and the class file of your generic enum wouldn't cause problems.

But in the end, enum is pretty much a syntax sugar. In C, C++, C#, enums are basically alias for int constants. Java gives it more power, but it is still *supposed* to represent simple items.

Somewhere people have to draw the line. Just because a class has enumerated instances, doesn't mean it must be an enum. If it is sophisticated enough in other areas, it deserves to be a regular class.

In your case, there is not much advantage to make `DataType` an enum. You can use enum in switch-case, that's about it, big deal. The non-enum verion of `DataType` works just fine.

Comment: I see your point. But the point of having `equals()`, `hashCode()`, `toString()`, `Serializable`, `Comparable`, `values()`, `valueOf()`, etc implemented is a big plus for `enum` as well. That's usually the reason, why I choose `enum`, not just the `switch-case` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think of it -

Regular classes have instances. You create a new instance of a class use it for some purpose and then dispose it. For example `List<String>` is a list of strings. I can do what ever I want to do with strings and then when I am done I can later do the same functionality with integers.

To me enumerators are not types that you create instances of. Its same thing as a singleton. So I can see why JAVA wouldn't allow generics for Enums because you really can't create a new instance of type Enum to use temporary like you do with classes. Enums are supposed to be static and only have one instance globally. To me, it wouldn't make sense to allow generics for a class that only has one instance globally.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does make sense to me. I provided a good example of why I want to do this. It works with the classic way of creating typesafe enums. But not with the `enum` way. And a static instance is still an instance. Why shouldn't it have a generic type parameter?

Comment: @Tom - What do you mean? If I create an enum Color{red, green, white} there is only one Color.white in the system. I have declared Color once and there is only one instance of Color.

Comment: @Amir Raminfar There are three instance of `Color` there: `red`, `green` and `white`.

Comment: No there are three instances of `Color`. Check out the generated byte code. They're `public static final Color` instances!

Comment: @Lukas, while I might agree with you, I think it would be more confusing. Static instance are not an instance. For example the Math class in java. Would it make sense to create a Math<Integer> and Math<Long>? I don't know if I am explaining this right. But in C++ generics are called templates. Because a class is really a template of something you are trying to do. But static classes are not templates. There is only one way you can do it. Am I making sense?

Comment: Correct, I didn't mean three instance of Color, I meant only one instance of Red. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Amir, you're mixing things up. `Math` has **NO** instances! Only static methods!

Comment: I guess what you are saying is you should be able to create enum Color<T> {Red<Integer>, Green<String>} I can see how that would be useful.

Comment: @Lukas, No I think I know what static methods are vs singleton. Static methods is Math.*. Singleton is only one instance of that class. I am talking about the former (Math class) You can't create a new instance of Color.Red. Just like you can't create a new instance of Math. Right?

Comment: @Amir. Exactly. I want to do that. While types for colours don't appear useful, I think my example is a much more realistic use case.

Comment: @Lukas and Tom - I should have worded my answer differently. With enums, once you declare your types then that's all you have. You can't at runtime create a new instance of Color. Since in Java, generics is really only for compile time, then I can see why it doesn't support enum generics.

Comment: Thanks. I am really thinking I am on to something! What's the point of generics if you can't create a new instance _after_ it has been defined. Maybe we can get this feature in JDK7 :)

Comment: @Amir. I know. That's the type erasure. An entirely different story we have to live with... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason why you wish to parameterize the enum with `<T>` boils down to being able to have different method signatures for the various constants of the enum.

In your example, the signature (type of parameters and return type) for `parse` would be:

- for `Datatype.INT`: `int parse(String)`
- for `Datatype.VARCHAR`: `String parse(String)`
- and so on

So how would the compiler be able to typecheck something like:

```
Datatype type = ...
...
int x = type.parse("45");
```

???

To apply static typing and typechecking to this kind of expression, the signature of the method must be *the same for all the instances*. However, in the end you suggest to have different method signatures for different instances... That's why it's not possible to do it in Java.

Comment: Then tell me how this would be possible in the 1.4-way of implementing typesafe enums (yes it is possible), but not with an `enum`?

Comment: N.B: The compiler does this to your example: `int x = ((Integer) type.parse("45")).intValue()`

Comment: In 1.4 you have “constants” (instances actually) of *different types*: INT is of type Datatype<Integer>, VARCHAR of type Datatype<String> and so on. These types are incompatible with each other. And this is incompatible with the definition (understand use cases) of an enum, for which the constants have to be of the same type!

Comment: `Datatype` has a generic parameter (or would), so `Datatype<Integer> type = ...`.

Comment: @Lukas, yes you're right about the unboxing thing, but it's not my point. My point was: “how does the compiler know that parse returns an Integer?” Indeed, it could be a Long, a String, and so on. And the compiler does not have this information.

Comment: Yes, I know. But **why** do they have to be of the same type as understood by Java < 1.5 **AND** of the same generic type as understood by `java.lang.Enum<?>`? Why? I'm going nuts over this question

Comment: @Tom: the point of an enum is having a bunch of constants of the *same* type, right? With what you propose you break this requirements, because the constants of the enum would be of different types...

Comment: @ChrisJ: But maybe at the time the `enum` JSR was written, speaking of *same types* meant types as understood before generics... Are you sure about what you're saying?

Comment: @Lukas: I think the problem is the same for Java 1.4 or 1.5. You want a bunch of constants of a *given* type, because you want to call methods on a *variable* of that type (without knowing which constant it actually contains). To be able to do this the method signatures *must not change* accross the various constants. It does not come from 1.4 or 1.5, it just comes from the fact that Java is statically typed.

Comment: @ChrisJ: That's why the compiler erases generic type info. So at runtime, my generic constants would be of the same type again. But the compiler knew more. That's why the compiler can generate type casts into byte code. It's not the method signatures that change. Casting is generated!

Comment: @Lukas: I suggest you to stop thinking in terms of 1.4 or 1.5. Go back to your example in 1.4. Are you able to actually do something with your example? I mean, do something one usually intends to do with enums? EDIT: I did not mean "example in 1.4", but rather your example with generics, but without using `enum`. See what I mean? Try to find an example of what you intend to do with it.

Answer (score -1):

```
public enum GenericEnum<T> {
  SIMPLE, COMPLEX;

  public T parse(String s) {
    return T.parse(s);
  }
}

public void doSomething() {
  GenericEnum<Long> longGE = GenericEnum<Long>.SIMPLE;
  GenericEnum<Integer> intGE = GenericEnum<Integer>.SIMPLE;

  List<Long> longList = new LinkedList<Long>();
  List<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

  assert(longGE == intGE);              // 16
  assert(stringList.equals(intList));   // 17

  Object x = longGE.parse("1");  // 19
}
```

The asserts at line 16 and 17 are both true.  The generic types are not available at run time.

One of the advantages of an enum is that you can use == to compare them.  The assert at line 16 will evaluate to true.

At line 19 we run into a problem though.  longGE and intGE are the same object (as the assert at line 16 shows.) What will be returned by the parse("1")?  The generic type information is not available at run time.  So there would be no way to determine T for the parse method at run time.

Enums are basically static, they only exist once.  And it doesn't make sense to apply generic typing to static types.

I hope this helps.

Note - this is not meant to be working code.  It is using the syntax suggested in the original question.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this will work: `... = GenericEnum<Long>.SIMPLE`, because `GenericEnum.SIMPLE` is a constant. It's generic type `<T>` has been bound finally (i.e. `SIMPLE` is actually `public static final GenericEnum SIMPLE;`) and cannot be changed anymore. You could unsafely cast it, i.e. `GenericEnum<Long> longGE = (GenericEnum<Long>) GenericEnum.SIMPLE;`, but as I said, that's an unsafe cast...