# How to receive typespecific Class for specific enum?

Tags: java, generics, enums, converters

I need some kind of Converter-Mapper and don't come up with any good idea, how to easily attach an enum with an special converter. I tried the following:

```
//ConverterInterface:
public interface PropertyConverter<T>
{
  public String convertObjectToString( T object );

  public T convertStringToObject( String string );
}

//Concrete Converter
public class FooConverter implements PropertyConverter<Foo>
{

  @Override
  public String convertObjectToString( Foo object )
  {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Not implemented yet." );
  }

  @Override
  public Foo convertStringToObject( String string )
  {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException( "Not implemented yet." );
  }
}

//Dataclass
public class Foo
{
}
```

Same goes for Boo, and here the enum, where I want to attach the Converter to a specific type:

```
public enum PropEnum
{
  BOO(new BooConverter()),

  FOO(new FooConverter());

  PropertyConverter<?> converter;

  private PropEnum( PropertyConverter<?> converter )
  {
    this.converter = converter;
  }

  public PropertyConverter<?> getConverter()
  {
    return converter;
  }
}
```

But since my PropertyConverter uses a Wildcard, I only get Object To String, and String To Object Methods instead of concrete types, like Foo To String and String To Foo, when I use it like the following:

[image: enumConverter]

Is there any way to receive the concrete type from the converter implementation?

Comment: related if not duplicate: [Java enums and generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108733/java-enums-and-generics).

Comment: @Paul Bellorca: I am aware, that I can't use generics with enums, I just thaught there might be an idea to work around this. Anyway thank you for that link.

Comment: @Jeffrey may I ask, how you would achieve this behaviour without using enums?

Comment: @ymene It depends on what you're trying to do, but you could have `Map<Class<T>, PropertyConverter<T>>` in some class and allow `PropertyConverter`s to be registered / retrieved.