# Overriding methods in Java Enums with Generics

Tags: java, generics, enums, overriding

I want a typed, implementation specific method for this enumeration. The compiler doesn't like the `@Override` annotation, but I'm confused as to why. More importantly, how can I make a method that compares these 2 (typed) objects?

```
public enum BrokenToy{

    BROKEN_ARROW {
                @Override
                public <T extends Set<Object>> double compare(
                        T prop1, T prop2) {
                    return 1.0;
                }
            };

    public abstract <T> double compare(T prop1, T prop2);
}
```

The ideal answer would be that I've gunked up the notation, and I need to change some syntax, but alas... [sad duck-face]. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108733/java-enums-and-generics) would have been another way to deal with the current challenge (Oh, it doesn't work? How perceptive). Typing within the method feels unclean, so let's look at that as a last resort.

Comment: What are you trying to do? How do you compare two `Set<Object>`s and how does that relate to a `BROKEN_ARROW` and `BrokenToy`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 'how can I make a method that compares these 2 (typed) objects?'

Comment: What does _these 2_ refer to? `prop1` and `prop2`? Why are they `Set<Object>`? How would you compare them? What's the comparison method? How is the client code intended to use the `compare` method?

Comment: Gosh, it looks like they are arbitrary objects which could be compared in a 'compare' method and that client code would get a double out of the comparison.

Comment: I'm asking for some context. Why does this need to be within an `enum`? Why can't you just create a `Comparator`? [What is an XY-problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Someone else's code is using the enum - I suppose I could completely re-write their stuff. Also, I'm not ordering these objects - perhaps 'similarity' would be a better method name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71278/discussion-between-user121330-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 4):

The `abstract` `compare` method allows you to use any reference type as a type argument.

Your implementation in `BROKEN_ARROW` does not. The compiler can therefore not allow it. It would break inheritance/polymorphism.

That's why your program won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with enums. In fact, you can't do it with any class.

If you could, it would break the [Liskov substitution principle](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Liskov_substitution_principle), which is basically that "if you can refer to an object as its super type, then you have to be able to use it as its super type."

Consider if someone did this:

```
BrokenToy toy = BrokenToy.BROKEN_ARROW;
double cmp = toy.compare(123, 456);
```

That would work according to the contract in `BrokenToy`, since Java would infer that `T` is of type `Integer`. But it'd fail at run time, since `BROKEN_ARROW` requires `T` to be a `Set<Object>`.

Instead, you should declare the generic on the class itself (which has to be an `abstract`, non-enum class):

```
public abstract class BrokenToy<T> {
    public abstract double compare(T prop1, T prop2);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: ' declare the generic on the class itself (which has to be an abstract, non-enum class).' - could you elaborate? This feels closer to an answer, but I still don't get it...

Comment: Is there any way to get the compiler to throw an error on the snippet that you wrote?