# Java enums may not have type parameters - why?

Tags: java, enums

It appears, that java enums may not have type parameters. I wonder - why? Why was this restriction introduced into java?

Why I want this ability? Consider `enum` which represents several instances with different type of internal structures, for example:

```
public enum ListHolderEnum<T> {

   A<String>, B<Integer>, C<Byte>;   

   private List<T> list;

   public List<T> getList() {
      return list;
   }     
}
```

It would be nice to have an ability of creation such structures :(

Comment: there is a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters). see if that answers your question

Comment: Duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters)