# Get instance of generic class from an enum attribute in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting, enums

I have an enum in my class which contains an Class attribute, as so:

```
public enum DatEnum {
  CONSTANT_ONE(ClassOne),
  CONSTANT_TWO(ClassTwo);

  private Class<? extends UpperBoundClass> classAttribute;

  private DatEnum(Class<? extends UpperBoundClass> classAttribute) {
    this.classAttribute = classAttribute;
  }

  public <T extends UpperBoundClass> T getInstance() {
    UpperBoundClass instance = classAttribute.newInstance();
    return instance;
  }
}
```

But then I get a warning in the first line of the getter:

> Unchecked cast from capture#4-of ? extends UpperBoundClass to T

And also in the second line of the getter:

> Unchecked cast from UpperBoundClass to T

So far the code works, but i'd really like to get rid of the warning as well as to have a better understanding of what the problem actually is here.

Comment: You have no enum constants there.

Comment: Also, do you mean `newInstance`?

Comment: Technically, all you need is a semi-colon above the field declaration, but it's *really weird* that you could do something like that.

Comment: Yes @SotiriosDelimanolis, i meant newInstance, the question is updated now, i also added enum constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public <T extends UpperBoundClass> T getInstance() {
  UpperBoundClass instance = classAttribute.newInstance();
  return instance;
}
```

**This code does *not* actually return `<T>`**. It returns an instance of the specific `Class<? extends UpperBoundClass>` referenced by the `classAttribute` field.  All the compiler can verify is that `instance` is assignable to (able to be cast to) `UpperBoundClass`.  However, there is no declared relationship between that instance and the *specific type* represented by `<T>` in the method signature.

End result: you're going to get a warning.  It might *happen to work* as long as every place you use `CONSTANT_ONE` or `CONSTANT_TWO` is already expecting the same type as you put in their respective constructors, but the compiler can't enforce or know that.

If you change your method to the following, then you will see the usage sites (in the calling code) that are not strictly type-safe because they assume a particular subclass:

```
public UpperBoundClass getInstance() {
  return classAttribute.newInstance();
}
```

Alternatively, you can provide some relationship between your `<T>` and the stored class reference:

```
public <T extends UpperBoundClass> T getInstance(Class<T> type) {
  UpperBoundClass instance = classAttribute.newInstance();
  return type.cast(instance); // verifies type-safety
}
```

But there's little point in doing that, because the caller could either call `type.newInstance()` itself or simply `new ClassOne()` (depending on the use case). The call to `type.cast(instance)` could throw `ClassCastException` at runtime, but the compiler will be happy because it considers it *your* problem at that point.

You're fighting the fact that **an `enum` presents a *uniform contract***; and while you can customize individual constants with polymorphic behavior, you cannot use generics to parameterize the `enum`'s *base API* with something that varies from instance to instance.

Related reading: [Why shouldn't Java enum literals be able to have generic type parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you William! I just changed getInstance() to what you wrote and no usage sites were type-unsafe. I'm wondering though, will getInstance() then return an instance of UpperBoundClass or an instance of the subclass specified in the constructor?

Comment: `Class.newInstance()` always returns an instance of the _exact_ type represented by the `Class` instance.  In your question, that's `ClassOne.class` for `CONSTANT_ONE` and `ClassTwo.class` for `CONSTANT_TWO`.  However, it _appears in the API_ to be nothing more specific than `UpperBoundClass` and callers cannot depend on any API that's not available in the upper bound without downcasting (and potentially getting a `ClassCastException`).  As long as your callers only need to use methods on `UpperBoundClass`, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,your `enum` class does not have enum constants.Secondly,I believe that your `Enum` Object will have `Class` `Object` as  its memeber variables.In most of the cases,you will have a single Object for each class(unless you are using multiple classLoaders for loading a class),so why not use a simple data structure containing only Class Objects.

As it is ,you can always use a `Class.newInstance()` or `Class.getDeclaredConstructors()` to get the `Constructor` and sue it to have your own Instance.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand this correctly but the idea here is to have an upper bound to the `Class` `Object` member variable to provide some sort of warranty regarding what the actual instance can accomplish.