# Troubles with generics while trying to call a method

Tags: java, validation, generics

I'm trying do develop a static validation method for my Java application. I'm using validator objects with `validate(T data)` methods and enums to store them. Follows a snippet of my code.

```
public enum ValidationType {
    TAX_CODE(null); // FIXME

    private final DataValidator<?> validator;

    private ValidationType(DataValidator<?> validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }
}

public static <T> void validate(T data, ValidationType dataType) {
    dataType.validator.validate(data);
}

private static abstract class DataValidator<T> {
    public abstract Class<T> getType();
    public abstract void validate(T data);
}
```

While editing, using Eclipse, I've got an error when I call the validate method (line `dataType.validator.validate(data);`).

Eclipse says:

> The method validate(capture#3-of ?) in the type ValidationUtil.DataValidator is not applicable for the arguments (T)

I cannot understand this messaga. How can I fix or modify, if possible, the code in order to let it works?

Thank you in advance for comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `validator` in your enum is of type `DataValidator<?>` which will not match `DataValidator<T>`.

However, you could work around that by creating an accessor method for the field that has the correct signature:

```
      public <T> DataValidator<T> getValidator() {
          return (DataValidator<T>)validator;
      }
```

You will need to cast here because you are assuming that the type passed in `T` actually belongs to the enum constant used.

In other words, the system won't be able to prevent you from doing silly things like:

```
TAX_CODE.getValidator().validate(new HashMap<>());
```

There will be no check that `TAX_CODE` has to be a `String`, it will fail at run-time with a `ClassCastException`.

Here's the adjusted code:

```
  public enum ValidationType {
      TAX_CODE(null); // FIXME

      private final DataValidator<?> validator;

      private ValidationType(DataValidator<?> validator) {
          this.validator = validator;
      }

      public <T> DataValidator<T> getValidator() {
          return (DataValidator<T>)validator;
      }
  }

  public static <T> void validate(T data, ValidationType dataType) {
      dataType.getValidator().validate(data);
  }

  private static abstract class DataValidator<T> {
      public abstract Class<T> getType();
      public abstract void validate(T data);
  }
```

**Update**

A rewritten proposal:

If you declare the `DataValidator`s as constants like this, then they would be type safe:

```
public static class Validators {
    public static final DataValidator<String> TAX_CODE_VALIDATOR = ...;
}
```

Usage:

```
Validators.TAX_CODE_VALIDATOR.validate("12345");
```

Comment: The cast unfortunately makes it so that the code is not type-safe anymore.

Comment: Since the enum itself is not generic, which is your starting point for triggering a validation, it couldn't be type safe anyway.  I think it can be done if you replace the enum with classes.

Comment: Yes, that's an unfortunate limitation of enums in Java. There is a [proposal to allow enums to have type parameters](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/301), so this might change in a future version of Java.

Comment: I like this solution with `getValidator()` method. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You get that error because you are using generic wildcards and your code is not type-safe.

`dataType.validator` is a `DataValidator<?>`, which means: a `DataValidator` of some unknown type (indicated by the `?`). When you call `validate()` on that with a value of some type `T`, the compiler complains, because the type that the `DataValidator` accepts is unknown. So, it cannot check if the type `T` is a type that should be allowed for this `DataValidator`.

One solution is to not use generic wildcards.

The problem is complicated by the fact that you have this in an `enum`, and [enums cannot have type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290878/why-shouldnt-java-enum-literals-be-able-to-have-generic-type-parameters) (at least, not yet - this might become a feature in a future version of Java). This, for example, is not allowed:

```
public enum ValidationType<T> { // Not valid Java! (at least not in Java 8)
    TAX_CODE(null); // FIXME

    private final DataValidator<T> validator;

    // etc.
}
```

What you can do instead is have a class with constants:

```
public final class ValidationType<T> {
    public static final ValidationType<String> TAX_CODE = new ValidationType<>(...);
    public static final ValidationType<Integer> SOMETHING = new ValidationType<>(...);
    public static final ValidationType<Double> ANOTHER = new ValidationType<>(...);

    private final DataValidator<T> validator;

    private ValidationType(DataValidator<T> validator) {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    public DataValidator<T> getValidator() {
        return validator;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the issue.